# Shopify. How to resuse a select setting across multiple schemas

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a section `sections/two-col-cta.liquid` with a schema defined as per below:

```
    {% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Two Column CTA",
    "class": "section",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "color_select",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "option_1",
            "label": "option_1"
          },
          {
            "value": "option_2",
            "label": "option_2"
          },
          {
            "value": "option_3",
            "label": "option_3"
          },
          {
            "value": "option_4",
            "label": "option_4"
          },
          {
            "value": "option_5",
            "label": "option_5"
          }
        ],
        "default": "image_first",
        "label": "t:sections.two-col-content-img.settings.layout.label",
        "info": "t:sections.two-col-content-img.settings.layout.info"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

This same `color_select` setting is used/duplicated across multiple different sections (sections/.liquid files). Is there a way I can define this setting globally and just pull it into my sections instead of re defining it every time I want to a color select?

Comment: if it added to sections, then it scoped to sections and you need to add each time. if added settiings it will avaible to whole theme files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So in order to create a re usable input, I need to define it inside the settings? What settings? And how would I reference that setting inside my sections     {% schema %} {% endschema %} ?

Comment: you need to add it under config foler into theme, you can directly use it into theme code, no need to add into section schema

Comment: settings_schema.json holds the settings that are avialble on whole theme code.